# Confusion with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This should be really simple but feels like I'm missing something.

Consider that we have random variables that influence each other as per $z \rightarrow x \rightarrow y$. Then $y$ is independent of $z$ conditional on $x$. Namely we get:

$$\begin{align}
p(y|x, z) &= p(y|x) \\
\frac{p(y, x, z)}{p(x, z)} &= \frac{p(y, x)}{p(x)}
\end{align}
$$
if we integrate out $x$ from the two sides we get:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{p(y, z)}{p(z)} &= p(y)=p(y|z)
\end{align}
$$
which seems to suggest that $y$ and $z$ are independent of each other, which doesn't make sense as surely knowing the value of $z$ tells us something about the distribution of $y$. Am I doing something wrong with my integrating out step?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how you mean to "integrate over x" here when you have quotients.

Comment: The only way $z$ affects $y$ is through $x$. If you are averaging or integrating over every possible value of $x$, then yes, you have destroyed the influence of $z$ on $y$. But conditional independence is not the same as independence.  I just don't see how those integrals play out.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably true but my final equation $p(y)=p(y|z)$ can't be correct still, but seems like integrating the quotients is the problem.

Comment: In general, neither
$$
\int\frac{p(y,x)}{p(x)}dx= p(y)
$$
nor
$$
\int\frac{p(y,x,z)}{p(x,z)}dx= \frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)}\ ,
$$
is necessarily true.  What we do have is
$$
p(y)=\int p(y,x)dx=\int \frac{p(y,x,z)p(x)}{p(x,z)}dx
$$
and
$$
\frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)}=\frac{\int p(y,x,z)dx}{\int p(x,z)dx}\ ,
$$
but I don't see how either of these identities can lead to $\ p(y)=\frac{p(y,z)}{p(z)}\ $.

Comment: Indeed, these seem obvious now -- not sure what I was thinking. Thank you!